# fancybox link redirects browser to image path

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm trying to display which is zoomed in a fancybox(2) when clicked. The problem is that when clicking on the image although it is correctly displayed inside the fancybox the browser navigates away from the page and goes to the link defined in the href. How can I prevent this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers :{
      title :{
         type : 'over'
      }
     }
   });
 });
</script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="fancybox ui-link" title="My Image href="http://localhost/images/my_image.jpg"><img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="images/my_image.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: check that you close your `title` attribute properly.. there is a missing quote at the end `title="My Image` ...also, when you say the "browser navigates away" does it mean that fancybox is closed and the image opened in the browser window?

Comment: fancybox stays open but the browser follows the link action so in this case it goes to http://localhost/images/my_image.jpg

Comment: so how come fancybox stays open? can you share any link or create a test page to see the issue. Not sure I am following you.

Comment: this jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/7b2WP/1/ kind of simulates my page. In my case when I click on the image the fancybox does not appear ontop of the page but on top of an empty page. i.e, is executing a GET request to the image URL

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong and honestly I don't see how I or somebody else can help. I corrected the basic html syntax errors in your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7b2WP/4/ and fancybox works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but ... it can help someone.

I had the same issue and realized that we have use **data-src** instead of **href*:

```
<a data-fancybox="image" data-src={{asset('uploads/sobre/'.$itemimage)}}"  data-caption="{{$item->title}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a " missing for the Title attribute in your html code.

Second, I'm not sure but you should try with relative path to your image instead of absolute path.

For instance :

```
<a class="fancybox ui-link" title="My Image" href="images/my_image.jpg"><img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="images/my_image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Did you try without fancybox option? Like $("a.fancybox").fancybox();